# What is the font used in the Elysium movie code editor?

Tags: font-identification

What is the font used in code editor in the Elysium movie?

[image: shot of code from movie]

[See here if the image link broke.](http://moviecode.tumblr.com/post/72085373569/in-the-film-elysium-the-space-station-is-rebooted)

Comment: I have a set of DIN stencils somewhere which produce that font, for use in engineering drawings (The image shows a monospaced version; my stencils are not).

Comment: it is also very close to (but isn't) lucida console

Comment: Wow, you are right, that _is_ a headache! What is tripping me up is the open 4 and the 1 without feet. It is pretty close to Droid sans mono... http://damieng.com/blog/2007/11/14/droid-sans-mono-great-coding-font

Comment: [Cicle](http://www.dafont.com/cicle.font?text=14+MOV+EAX_scratch) looks similar

Comment: if someone looks for a solution: pay attention to "t" which looks like a cross, i - has very special upper serif, C ends are straight, middle part of W is lower then external parts....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like FF Isonorm Monospaced Regular. Initially sold by FontFont but not seemingly available anymore. [Typekit](https://typekit.com/fonts/isonorm) has a similar looking font but its spacing is proportional and you will find differences in some glyphs because of this (e.g. i, j, etc.).

[image: FF Isonorm Monospaced Regular]

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Done! ... three years later! ;-)

Comment: @Emilie the link is dead though `(–_–)`

Comment: @WELZ Yes looking for a replacement but doesn't seem to be sold by a foundry anymore. I'll just remove it if I don't find anything official