# Which font is used in this image? This is taken from an old Transmission Line and Grid Station specification drawing

Tags: font-identification

[image: Font to be indentified]

Can someone please identify the font appearing in this image. The image is taken from an old drawing for Transmission Line and Grid Station specifications. As this drawing is only available in Hard copy and I want to reconstruct it in Autocad and for that, I need to identify this font.[image: Another Image from the same source]
[image: A third image from the same source]

[image: A larger image having similar font]

Comment: Hey user30208, welcome to GD! You might find some answers  on how to figure out what font this is by checking our [font section](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/guidelines-for-font-identification-questions) Questions that show some effort or tell us what you have tried already tend to get good answers. Don't be discouraged though :)

Answer (score 3):

It's an Isonorm stencil, which is how the tail of Q is misplaced. I used to have a set for just this sort of drawing; here's one from [Moebius-Ruppert](http://moebius-ruppert.com/zeichen/z_details/92050060_en.html)...

[image: Isonorm Stencil]

You can get [Isonorm from Fontshop](http://www.fontshop.com/search/?q=isonorm) -- there are a large number of variants.

[image: FF Isonorm by FontFont]

See also [a related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26804/what-is-the-font-used-in-the-elysium-movie-code-editor)

Comment: Given the date (90s) this likely was not hand stenciled, but rather plotted.

Comment: @DA01 Possibly; but the top "Schedule of Quantities" was definitely hand-stencilled unless there was gross movement of the medium. And I think I'd expect margins to be **dead** straight.

Comment: Possibly...though my thought was that the baseline shift was caused from the scanning/photographing of physical media into whatever archive this might have become at the time (microfiche?)--but hand stenciling is a good theory too.

Answer (score -1):

I run into this problem all the time...and luckily there are loads of websites that can help you out. If you find yourself doing this multiple times per day...there are also plugins. After viewing the image, i would still suggest **starting** with the websites i list, and then post on the [Typophile](http://typophile.com/fontid) forum.

Feel free to add any websites you think have a higher success rate and i will modify my answer to include those i've used before or any site i find would be a more suitable alternative.

**In the order i use them:**

http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

http://www.whatfontis.com/

http://www.identifont.com/

for PDF's, read [this article](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-i-automatically-determine-fonts-used-in-an-image-or-pdf) from the community. You can use *Adobe Reader plugins*, **OR** the *properties of the PDF will list what fonts have been embedded*.

**If you are still have problems finding a font, or similar font, [Typophile](http://typophile.com/fontid) is wonderful community to reach out to. Please note that forum #29 is not where you post these. The correct forum, at Typophile, for identifying fonts can be located at http://typophile.com/fontid**

Comment: for images that are extremely old, or scans of something equally aged...it's a good idea to find out roughly HOW OLD it is. That can tell us a lot about the font, actually. Think back to windows 95...while there were still loads of fonts to be used...most companies stuck to a very small set of fonts. So if this scan is roughly twenty years old, chances are you can google what windows 95/98 came with and pick out the most used fonts and it may just be one of those! find out how old this piece of paper is and let us know!

Comment: This is useful info, but doesn't actually answer the question. This would be better posted as an answer to a new question "What are sites/resources for ID'ing fonts"?

Answer (score -1):

Given the era (90s) this is likely an embedded plotting font within the CAD software (likely AutoCAD) or the plotter/printer itself.

So, it's not necessarily going to be a digital font you can just purchase. That said, if you'd like something similar, search for 'plotter' or 'architect' at myfonts or the like.